# Problem after closing with bend modifier

Tags: mesh

I bent my shape, and erased double vertices.

I can move them and the shape is well closed, but when I use subdivision it remains with a rounded end.

I know I can make a cylinder, but this is a test for more complex work.

Any idea how to close it properly?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps there's an internal face where the two sides connect?

Comment: ^ What he said, was just about to publish an answer saying that.

Comment: @stphnl329, you should undelete your answer. As you took time to do it, it is ok to keep it, even if in between a comment says the same.

Comment: @lemon alright, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've created that band by bending a rectangular prism then removing doubles, I believe there's an extra face that you didn't delete, right in the center where the two ends had met (running along the cross-section of the band). You need to delete that inner face since the subdivide modifier is using that face to average out the vertices.

Comment: Great !! thanks :-) Is there an other way to close a bended prism? It's easy to remove a face on a simple vertex but on a more complex one...

Comment: @Shura Create a cylinder with n vertices, select *Nothing* cap fill type, then apply a solidify modifier

Comment: If its not a regular polygon, you can also use the *Inset* tool while in edit mode. A shortcut is to select a face and press "I"

Comment: many thanks for all your anwsers, very helpful :-)